# Certain apps cannot "see" a drive mounted at /projects, but mainstream linux apps are fine

Tags: mount, filesystem, libreoffice, snap, automount

I have a second HDD set up that automounts to /projects (a linux-nonstandard location but one used by some CAD tools). Point being to make the design self contained and transportable.

Basic Linux apps (shell, text edit, even some third party CAD tools) navigate fine to this mount point. But others (gimp, LibreOffice) have file "choosers" which will not pick up the plain fact that /projects -is- mounted or even exists.

What should I do differently, to make the second drive "reveal itself" to these stubborn apps' lame file browsers?

Comment: You've provided no specific details; what base OS/release are you talking about, what application, what package type... as some package types (eg. *snap* packages which run *confined* by default) will not be able to do that, but without specifics as to what OS/release, nor details of the package - your question is not currently answerable  (*some Ubuntu products prevent access as a security feature, but we don't know what product you're using thus if this is the issue*).

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop mode.

The GIMP came with the distro and it can't see the mount point. I did not install the package myself; went to, and it said already installed. 

But at the same time File Manager does, and I can cd to the folders there from the command line. 

LibreOffice also fails to check the real filesystem for this mount-point, just doesn't display it at the / node in its internal browser although other tools (mostly) will.

Comment: Additional details (*or corrected details*) should be added to your question.  Comments are about the question itself & get removed once the question contains/deals with the commented queries  (*this is a Q&A site and not a forum*).

Comment: And so which do you call an "answer", which is what I put? Which is one of the options offered and maybe its own thing.

Answer (score 0):

OK. From digging around I find that "snap" installed LibreOffice has this problem (maybe my other troubled apps as well, will see about The GIMP).
My system actually had a "snap" later Libreoffice installed over the distro-provided version.

I removed them all, added the LibreOffice PPA, did an apt install and now LibreOffice will browse to my /projects (automounted on secondary HDD) as it should.

Here's the 'history'

dpkg --list | awk '/ii/&&/libreoffice/||/libobasis/{print $2}' | sudo xargs apt purge --yes

sudo apt autoremove --yes

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa --yes

which libreoffice

sudo snap remove libreoffice

sudo snap list --all libreoffice

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install libreoffice-help-en-us

LibreOffice apps appears to be all working, 7.4.2 version even knows it's new.